# Did not get Route between two Geo points in OSMdroid using OSMBONUSPACK RoadManager?

Tags: osmdroid, osmbonuspack

I have used OSRMRoadManager and Pathoverlay in OSMdroid but didnt get route between two places it shows unfortunately after going this line
http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute?&loc=17.413389,78.465372&loc=17.3696,78.4326&instructions=true&alt=false
it's response is "Not found"
after this application is terminated.

Comment: Effectively, OSRM web demo is working fine, but OSRMRoadManager doesn't work => OSRM completely changed their API. We have to adapt OSRMRoadManager. In the meantime, you can try switching to GraphHopperRoadManager.

Comment: Well, in fact OSRM changed their API some time ago, and you are still using an outdated version of OSMBonusPack. Use the latest version.

Comment: Using GraphHopperRoadManager with key also didnt get route between feo points on map

Comment: Both are currently working fine when using the demo app OSMNavigator. You have something wrong in your code.